# How to fix programmatically webGL context lost (sad smile in chrome) that already happened?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl

I have iframe with canvas inside. After WebGL lost context I see:

[image: sad smile webgl issue]

Any animation on canvas can't be done, simple page reload doesn't help. Now I'm worried about how to fix programmatically consequence and not a cause. If a user is faced with such a problem, he has 2 ways (which are known to me) how to fix this issue:

1. Right-click on an iframe and select "Reload frame".

[image]

2. Close the browser completely and open it

What I have tried:

1. Reload iframe from js in the following ways:

   1.1 with `document.getElementById('iframe_id').ContentWindow.location.reload();`

   1.2 tried deleting iframe and re-creating

   1.3 tried to delete and create an iframe, but already changing the url of the frame
2. I tried to open the context menu with a reboot item and some how click on it.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61023200/128511), also [see the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.15)